# Get value of droplink in Code-Behind

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am trying to get the display name of an item in a droplink in the back-end C# code.  I am using Sitecore 6.6, not using MVC, and am setting a droplink control in the CMS for clients called `Address`. The droplink source goes to `/sitecore/Templates/User Defined/WAC/Address`, and the individual items have an SEO-compliant name and a readable display name.

For example:

- Item ID: {9E60F5F8-FBF2-4CBD-BB13-6A93397AAC87}
- Name: 100-main-street
- Display Name: 100 Main Street, Sample Town, 10011

My code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String sl = "";
    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item currentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
    // BEGIN main class list
    Sitecore.Collections.ChildList classList = currentItem.Children;
    foreach (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item mainPage in classList)
    {
        if (mainPage.TemplateID.ToString() == "{27A9692F-AE94-4507-8714-5BBBE1DB88FC}")
        {
            sl += "<span class=\"address\">" + mainPage.Fields["Address"] +"</span>";
        }                            
        else
        {
        }
    }
    // END main class list
    classSessionList.Text = sl;
}
```

This code will give me the ID of the Item. If I use `mainPage.Fields["Address"].DisplayName`, I get "Address".

How can I get the Display Name of the item from the droplink?

Answer (score 10):

Use **LookupField** for getting reference item below are the sample code:

```
LookupField address= (LookupField)mainPage.Fields["Address"];
Item addressItem = address.TargetItem;
string displayName = addressItem.Fields["DisplayName"].Value;
```

If you want it in one line then use below code:

```
((LookupField)mainPage.Fields["Address"]).TargetItem.DisplayName
```

Comment: Great answer, but also, null check all the things.

Answer (score 3):

Type cast the field to a ReferenceField. Then access the TargetItem property:

```
sl += "<span class=\"address\">" + ((ReferenceField)mainPage.Fields["Address"]).TargetItem.DisplayName +"</span>";
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for the great tips! I will be trying these out. :)

Answer (score 1):

The thomas answer would work based on your code. But I would suggest you also to try to stick with ASP.Net and Sitecore server components.

That will avoid Null Reference errors, will support Page Editor better and also makes your code easier to maintain.

You can have a repeater in your markup like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAdresses" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span class="address">
            <sc:Text id="scAddress" runat="server" Field="__Display Name" Item="<%#(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem%>"></sc:Text>
        </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then bind the address on your code behind:

```
private void BindRepeater()
{
    if (mainPage.TemplateID.ToString() != "{27A9692F-AE94-4507-8714-5BBBE1DB88FC}")
    {
        rptAdresses.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        rptAdresses.DataSource = Sitecore.Context.Item.GetChildren();
        rptAdresses.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Another point that I notice was the line `mainPage.TemplateID.ToString() != "{27A9692F-AE94-4507-8714-5BBBE1DB88FC}"`. That is a point that you also could improve. Hard coded IDs are not a good pratice. You could create a class to hold those things or, even better, you could think more about your design to avoid it.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

All other solutions are perfect, but you can also use the code below:

```
var itemID=mainPage.Fields["Address"].value;
Item targetItem=Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(itemID);

if (mainPage.TemplateID.ToString() == "{27A9692F-AE94-4507-8714-5BBBE1DB88FC}")
{
    sl += "<span class=\"address\">" + targetItem.DisplayName +"</span>";
}                            
else
{
}
```

With this approach you can use every field of target item.