# Sitecore getProperty field values of a drop link

Tags: sitecore

I've defined a list of Bootstrap column Values that allows the editor to define column width as a rendering parameter.

This is done by having a folder of Sitecore items and when I set the drop link to point at that folder I therefore get a drop down with numbers 1>12 for the editor to select.

I'm looking to obtain the field value of the droplink (labelled "Setting Value") but I am only receiving the GUID of the selected value how do I cast this to an item to be able to obtain its field values.

Thanks in advance

```
compiledClass += "col-md-" + GetProperty("Column Width Medium Device");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value of droplink in Code-Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282194/get-value-of-droplink-in-code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    var widthParameter = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Parameters["Width"];
    var selectedWidthItemId = new Sitecore.Data.ID(widthParameter);
    var widthItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(selectedWidthItemId);
    var widthValue = widthItem["Width value"];
    var compiledClass = "";
    compiledClass += "col-md-" + widthValue;
}

<div>
    CompiledClass is: @compiledClass
</div>
```

Example assumes that your rendering parameters template contains *'Width'* droplink field. And items within folder (source for droplink field) have *'Width value'* field.